# Check if numbers are between a specified set of numbers?

Tags: php, xml

This code:

```
$url = ('example.url');

function Feed($url) {
  $feed = simplexml_load_file($url) or die('Cannot Connect');
  $result = array();
  foreach ($feed->channel->item as $content) {
      array_push($result, $content);
  }
  return $result;
}
```

feed.php ^^

```
require_once 'feed.php';

    $title = '123';

    foreach(Feed('example.url') as $f ) {
        if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false)
            echo $f->children('georss', true)->children('gml', true)->children('gml', true). "<br>";
    }
```

**Output:**

```
59.838314 6.865717
59.662615 10.569110
59.709940 10.690916
```

How can I check if the numbers are between numbers I have specified?

**Example:**

Longitude between `59.68000` and `59.85000`

Latitude between `5.510000` and `8.750000`

it would output `59.838314 6.865717`

> EDIT: shows what if have tried:

```
    foreach(Feed('example') as $f ) {
      if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false)
        if ($f->children('georss', true)->children('gml', true)->children('gml', true) >= 59.68000 && $f->children('georss', true)->children('gml', true)->children('gml', true) <= 59.85000) {
          echo $f->children('georss', true)->children('gml', true)->children('gml', true). "<br>";
        }
    }
```

Here I only check for the longetude. I want to check for both.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to achieve your desired result?

Comment: yes, but they seem way off. I was hoping to get some ideas here I could explore further

Comment: We can't help you fix something we can't see.  Please include your attempts in your question along with the result and what debugging you have already done.

Comment: @PatrickQ updated

Comment: If your current code correctly checks for longitude (does it?) then what's stopping you from adding conditions for latitude?

Comment: I think you want the bccomp function. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php

Comment: @PatrickQ yes it checks for longitude now. I tried adding this: `if ($f->children('georss', true)->children('gml', true)->children('gml', true) >= 5.510000 && $f->children('georss', true)->children('gml', true)->children('gml', true) <= 8.750000) {}` but then output is nothing, when it should be `59.838314 6.865717`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around and found out this as the best solution for my problem:

```
    foreach(Feed($url) as $f ) {
      if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false){
        $pos = $f->children('georss', true)->children('gml', true)->children('gml', true);
        list($number1, $number2) = explode(' ', $pos);
          if ($number1 > 50.00000 && $number1 < 71.00000){
            if ($number2 > 4.510000 && $number2 < 10.750000){
             echo $f->children('georss', true)->children('gml', true)->children('gml', true). "<br>";
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing float values in PHP can be problematic.
You can use bccomp() to compare float values if that is what you are asking.

```
$a = '59.68000';
$b = '59.85000';
echo between($a, $b, '59.68001') . "\n"; // in range
echo between($a, $b, '59.68000') . "\n"; // exact match
echo between($a, $b, '59.88000') . "\n"; // higher than range
echo between($a, $b, '59.67000') . "\n"; // lower than range

function between($lower, $upper, $value)
{
    // Value is greater than lower bound of range
    $check1 = bccomp($value, $lower, 6) >= 0;
    // Value is less than upper bounds of range
    $check2 = bccomp($upper, $value, 6) >= 0;
    if ( $check1 && $check2 ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use the function:

```
foreach(Feed($url) as $f ) {
    if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false) {
        $long = $f->children('georss', true)->children('gml', true)->children('gml', true);
        $lat = $f->lattitude_value(); // Replace me!!
        if ( between('55.00000', '60.00000', $long) && between('5.510000', '8.750000', $lat) ) {
            echo $long . ' ' . $lat . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```